# Iterate table columns and get the results

Tags: php, mysql

I have `$columns` array

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Field] => category_id
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Field] => category_name 
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Field] => category_slug
        )

)
```

and `$products` array

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category_id] => 1
            [category_name] => Articulations
            [category_slug] => articulations
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category_id] => 2
            [category_name] => Card
            [category_slug] => card
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category_id] => 3
            [category_name] => Bar
            [category_slug] => bar
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category_id] => 4
            [category_name] => FOO
            [category_slug] => foo
        )
)
```

which has the column values.

How can I iterate through the columns and get the results of each column?

I tried with:

```
  <? foreach($columns as $column): ?>
          <tr data-id="">
                <?php foreach($produse as $produs): ?>
                <td><?= $produs->{$column->Field} ?></td>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
          </tr>
  <? endforeach; ?>
```

But the logic is not good and I understand why not, but I cant figure it out how to loop through `columns` and `products`.

Comment: Uh, why not just echo the product array keys instead? They seem to match the values of your columns array

Comment: I don't understand why this question was up voted 3 times.. Is just a question for a particular situation.. there is no new information we may learn from it.. It's interesting to find out why the users are up and down voting the questions

Comment: @Epodax based on a table parameter columns may be different each time. How do you suggest to match?

Comment: Could you show us the expected output? I'm struggling to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Something like this: http://i.imgur.com/YOuynSB.png where the heading of the table are the `$columns` and the rows are the `$products`.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're just missing referencing the `Field` property of your `column` objects:

```
<? foreach($columns as $column): ?>
      <tr data-id="">
            <?php foreach($produse as $produs): ?>
            <td><?= $produs->{$column->Field} ?></td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tr>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Does not show the results correclty. Field missing was only a typo mistake when I copied the code.